# How to get an "(all)" value for a level in a user defined hierarchy in SSAS/MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to work out how I can get a total for a level in a user defined hierarchy.  For example if I do (using Adventure works here):

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
([Date].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS * [Date].[Month of Year].ALLMEMBERS) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I get totals for each pair of year/month values.

How can I rewrite this query using the Calendar user hierarchy in the Date dimensions?  Eg something like:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
([Date].[Calendar].[Year] * [Date].[Calendar].[Month]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Using any hierarchy (no matter if it is a user hierarchy or an attribute hierarchy) in a cross join (denoted by `*`) is not possible in MDX. One hierarchy may only appear in one axis, and in one position within the axis. Your second statement would put the same hierarchy to position one and two of the rows axis.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks, and yes I understand that, I am asking if it is possible to write the top query in a way that will work but using the Calendar Hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
Hierarchize([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year] + [Date].[Calendar].[Month]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

This will show you each year containing its value (which is the sum of the months contained in it) before the months.

The `+` is the short form of `Union` in MDX, and `Hierarchize` sorts a set in hierarchical order, which means parents before children.

And if you want something similar to your first result, the closest thing I can imagine would be via calculated measures like this:

```
WITH Member Measures.Year AS
            IIf([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Level IS [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],
                [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name,
                Ancestor([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember, [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]).Name
               )
     Member Measures.Month AS
            IIf([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Level IS [Date].[Calendar].[Month],
                [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name,
                'All Months'
               )
SELECT {
        Measures.Year,
        Measures.Month,
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
       }
       ON 0,
Hierarchize([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year] + [Date].[Calendar].[Month]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Note that calculated members need not return numbers, they can as well return strings.

Comment: Thanks frank, I didn't know about the + operator, so that helps greatly.  The results are still slightly different from my original query though in that the Year and Month are on a single "position" on the axis.  So whereas the first query would have CY2005 | All Periods, the query above just has CY2005 and then the first month below.  Is there any way I can split the union across multiple positions on the axis?

Comment: @nzyme It is not possible to get exactly the same result as your first query, but you can come close, see my edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks frank, I appreciate your effort.  I guessed it may not be possible.  The reason I would like to get it into that format as I am processing the result set in c# with adomd.net, and it would be nice to treat crossjoins between different hierarchies and unions between a single hierarchy consistently.

Comment: @nzyme That is just not possible, as one hierarchy can only appear at one position in a query. This is just how MDX works. To require this  would be similar to request different rows to contain different columns in a SQL result: This just is not possible in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Using allmembers as you have it should return you the ALL line and then each year and each month. If you are interested in only the all line you can change you query to:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
([Date].[Calendar Year] * [Date].[Month of Year]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Notice how it is specifying only the Dimension and the hierarchy.

If you wanted to get the data without the all line use the following:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
([Date].[Calendar Year].children * [Date].[Month of Year].children) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```